# How to get tuple of numbers that fulfill a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code which works almost perfectly:

```
[(x+y) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [2,4,5] if x+y==7]
Out: (7,7)
```

Instead, I want the combination that yield the two 7's, so a tuple of (2,5),(3,4). How can this be done in the flat python code format?

Comment: `print([(x,y) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [2,4,5] if x+y==7])` you want to add the tuple `(x,y)` to your result, and not `(x+y)`

Comment: What about `[(x, y) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [2,4,5] if x+y==7]`?

Comment: @FrancisColas great, it worked! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically instead of adding the values on the return just

`[(x, y) for x in [2,3,4] for y in [2,4,5] if x+y==7]`

I expect this will give you the desired output you asked for.